# Why did Sidious never seek to turn Rey toward the dark side of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-rise-of-skywalker, rey

We learned from the film *Star Wars: Episode IX - The Rise of Skywalker* (2019) that Darth Sidious or Palpatine offered to Kylo Ren a new Sith Empire along with the title of Emperor but only if he killed Rey. Later on, Sidious rejected the notion that he wanted her dead, rather brought to him to succeed him as Empress Palpatine and finally he asked Rey to kill him in order to transfer his spirit from the decaying clone body into the youthful Rey's, but, in the same way as Sidious did with Anakin Skywalker and Kylo Ren and planned with Luke Skywalker, I have found no attempt from Sidious to lure/tempt/seduce his granddaughter to train her in the dark side of the Force and replace Kylo Ren as his next apprentice. Why?

[image: Still image from Star Wars The Rise of Skywalker]

Comment: Sidious did not have a great record with apprentices by that point. Rey had the potential to be stronger than Luke or Anakin, who already had damaged him pretty badly in the whole Death Star incident. Maybe he just realized it was a bad idea?

Comment: @Adamant that's actually Sith Culture...you are supposed to train the one that one day will kill u and take your place.

Comment: In fairness he didn't get much of a chance. She's invisible and hidden for much of her formative years and then actively combatant for the remainder

Answer (score 1):

**He just needed a young and trustful vessel for his spirit: Rey.**

By that time, Kylo Ren had been a pretty decent and strong apprentice. Dark Rey would reign as a Master and Ren as his second in command.

Comment: Why was Kylo not acceptable then? Why would Kylo accept Rey as master?

Comment: @Skooba - afaik, dark side Master Sidious accepted Ren as his apprentice ("At last. Snoke trained you well"). Regarding Rey, she would be no more herself but Dark Rey: Sidious embodiment to whom Ren should revere honor and blind obedience.

Comment: Also, gonna point out that Sidious had already tried the turn-good-guy-to-the-Dark-Side approach a time or two, and how'd it turn out in the long run?

Comment: @PeterNielsen, it could be noted that any time it looked like he had a couple of solid options he made them fight each other, which isn't a great plan for the long term.